# Odd behavior of SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, internationalization

Code:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMMdd", Locale.US);
Object o = simpleDateFormat.parse("20111216");
System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format((Date)o));
```

Output

```
20111226
```

Why? Giant bug?

Comment: 'Y' is not a valid SimpleDateFormat format character.

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'Y'` for me - are you sure this is exactly what you're running?

Comment: Which Java VM (vendor and version) are you using?

Comment: yes, ran many times, and not for once did it shout EXCEPTION!

Comment: You don't need to cast `o` into a `Date` when passing to `format`. `format` is expecting `Object`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it should be

`yyyyMMdd`

Note:  small letter `y`

**See Also**

- [API Doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

Once I fix the pattern (it should be `yyyyMMdd` with lowercase `y`), the code works as expected (it outputs `20111216`).

Answer (score 0):

I think the greater question hinted by the op on this has been missed.

Why is it that sometimes 'Y' works despite the docs. Yes it should be 'y', but on some systems 'Y' works.

I developed on a mac where 'Y' worked and it blew up on prod Linux where 'Y' didn't work. Not hard to realize what's going on, but very annoying.